# How to fix "no suitable conversion function from "String" to "const char *" exists"?

Tags: c++, string, syntax, char

I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish this, I have searched and tried many different things but I just cant get it to work?  strcpy(host, DATA); is what gives me the error.

```
char host[60] = "www.yahoo.com";

void loop() {
    String content = "";
    char character;
    while (Serial.available()) {
        character = Serial.read();
        content.concat(character);
    }
    if (content != "") {
        String CMD = getValue(content, '|', 0);
        String DATA = getValue(content, '|', 1);

        if (CMD == "SSID")
        {
            Serial.println("Your CMD is:" + CMD + " And your DATA is:" + DATA);
        }
        else if (CMD == "PASS")
        {
            Serial.println("Your CMD is:" + CMD + " And your DATA is:" + DATA);
        }
        else if (CMD == "HOST")
        {
            Serial.println("Your CMD is:" + CMD + " And your DATA is:" + DATA);

            strcpy(host, DATA);
        }
    }
    delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Is String a std::string? a custom class?

Comment: What is `String`? It's certainly not a `char*`, which is what `strcpy` expects. You need to convert `String` to a `const char*`, possibly through its member function. For example, `std::string` has a `c_str()` member function that does that.

Comment: I just dont understand what i can do 
            strcpy(host, "whatever"); but I cant  do 
            strcpy(host, DATA);

Comment: @JohnBrodowski Because C++ is strongly typed, and the type of `DATA` is `String`, which is not the same as `char *` or `const char*`, and also there is no implicit conversion from `String` to `char*` or `const char*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `String`, is a `std::string`, you can do

```
strcpy(host, DATA.c_str());
```

If it's a custom class for example

```
class String
{
char buffer[20];

//add a method c_str() for example like the std::string does

const char * c_str() { return buffer; }

//or just go yolo and overload the operator const char * like a boss

operator const char *() { return buffer;  }

};
```

and all you have to do now is `strcpy(buff, DATA)` and the `operator const char * ()` will be used.

Comment: I'd be careful with implicit conversion operators, as they may kick in whenever you will expect the least. In C++11 you can make them `explicit`, or just use the `c_str()` member function.

Comment: True, forgot about that.

Comment: Now you need a cast in `strcpy(buff, (const char*)DATA)` because it won't convert implicitly ;)

Comment: @vsoftco not really, because strcpy takes a a const char* as the second parameter.

Comment: Then a cast to `const char*`, sorry. But definitely you need to explicitly cast if your conversion operator is `explicit`, see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b48049baac0e5b0.